# How to validate email and password using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting state values while clicking submit button but I am unable to do the validation for my login form and how to display the error messages below the input field when I enter my input wrong or empty. please give me a solution to this.Thanks in advance.

```
const Login = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: ""
    });
    
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const {id, value} = e.target
        setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [id]: value
        }))
    }

    const handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Authenticated",state);
    }

    return(
        <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="title">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmitClick}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input 
                          type="email" 
                          className="email"
                          placeholder="Email"
                          value={state.email}
                          onChange={handleChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input 
                          type="password" 
                          className="password"
                          placeholder="Password"
                          value={state.password}
                          onChange={handleChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="button">Enter</button>
                 </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Will your validation be on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform client-side validation, you can create hook like this:

```js
const useEmailValidation = (email) => {
  const isEmailValid = /@/.test(email); // use any validator you want
  return isEmailValid;
};
```

And then you can use this hook in your form component:

```
...
const isEmailValid = useEmailValidation(state.email);
const isPasswordValid = usePasswordValidation(state.password);
const isFormValid = isEmailValid && isPasswordValid;

return (
  ...
    <input
      className={classNames({ 'invalid': !isEmailValid })}
      type="email"
      value={state.email}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    {!isEmailValid && 'Some error message'}
    <button type="submit" disabled={!isFormValid} className="button">Enter</button>
  ...
);
...
```

Your validator hook can return validation message instead of boolean, like:

```js
const useEmailValidation = (email) => {
  if (!email || email.length === 0) {
    return 'Email cannot be empty';
  }

  const isEmailValid = /@/.test(email); // use any validator you want
  if (!isEmailValid) {
    return 'Invalid email provided';
  }

  return null;
};
```

Also it is a good practice to show validation message only after field was focused before and after user tried to submit the form.

Comment: Can we call useEmailValidation a hook ? by definition doesn't a function to be entitled as a hook it must use stateful functions like useState etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Formik](https://formik.org/) is a great plugin that will help you perform form validation. The examples are also quite clear.

Or you could do something like this:

```
const Login = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const validateEmail = (email) => {
    const re =
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [id]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!validateEmail(state.email)) {
      setError('Invalid Email');
    }

    if (state.password.length < 8) {
      setError('Password must be at least 8 chars long');
    }

    if (!error) {
      // No errors.
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='title'>
          {error && <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</div>}
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmitClick}>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                type='email'
                className='email'
                placeholder='Email'
                value={state.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                type='password'
                className='password'
                placeholder='Password'
                value={state.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <button type='submit' className='button'>
              Enter
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

For an empty validation you can check it preventing the submit if the field is empty, like

```
const handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
  if(email.trim() === '' || password.trim() === ''){
       //Add a h1 or section with the error message
  }else{
        console.log("Authenticated",state);
  }
}
```

As long as the email field type is equal to email, which is your case, the browser should give an alert if the string is not an email. ("user@example.com")